# How to translate MySQL db schema into a raw sql code?

Tags: mysql, ssms

Is there a way to get a MySql database in SQL Code?

(In short: I have a db. I would like to get a code that, when executed, creates the database)

I need to 'replicate' a fairly large MYSQL db in python by running commands such as eg

```
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Product ("
                 "Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,"
                 "CreatedOn DATE NOT NULL")
```

but for a large db and I don't want to go over the db to manually translating the schema into alike code.
I searched Microsoft SQL management studio but I cannot find a suitable option.
Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: Write python code to generate python code..

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert a MySQL database into a SQLServer database?

Comment: Do you mean Script Table as -> Create To -> New Query Editor Window and then do a little patch up?

Comment: I would like to get a code that, when executed, creates the database

Comment: Are you using mysql or ms sql server? The question is tagged as mysql, but SSMS is for MS SQL Server.

Comment: Good note, I didn't describe very well, but the solution was found, I needed to get the MS SQL schema using SSMS and then I'm translating it into mysql, my bad.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer.

Comment: Please share more details - what **exactly** do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MSSMS Studio, you can use Script Table as->Create To->New Query Window (or File, Clipboard) on each table to generate the SQL commands necessary to create the tables.  Then you can edit as necessary for your application.